# Recording Mono with H2 or H4

Tags: zoom, h2, mono

I once again sincerely apologize if this is a newb question, but here goes:

I recorded quite a bit of stuff with my H2 in it's different configurations to get some good ambiences (one, by the way, was an awesome old schoolbus interior on a mountain dirt road with a bunch of mountain bikes hung up in the back of it. It had a huge deep engine and the rattling bikes made it sound like a tank! I'll upload it later for you all to hear)

But anyway, back to my question:

Have you ever wanted to record something with the H2 or H4 in mono, like a hard effect? And what did you do?

Do you point just one of the capsules at it instead of dead-on and then just use one side once you import the audio file into Pro Tools?

I couldn't find just a straight mono configuration.

Just wondering...

Answer (score 1):

Go into the menu and turn the Mono Mix into ON. It'll record a stereo file named MONO with the same content on both channels. H2 makes a mono mix of the two channels but i don't know why it doesn't create a mono file instead of a stereo one ... than you can take just one channel or combine the two into one to have a real mono channel. I assume the H4 has the same configuration but I'm non sure about that.

Comment: @fabio_iaci, what @Ryan was actually asking is not so much a question of "how to switch to mono recording" but rather "how to get the best mono recording out of a stereo mic and recorder". In other words, he was asking if he should record in mono (and pointing dead on) or stereo (and pointing one capsule only). So what do you say?

Comment: Sorry @Justin Huss, I think both approaches can be valid. It depends on what you need. For voices and interwiews I usually mix the two channels for FX I usually use one channel or, if necessary, manually mix the two channels shifting in time, phase or freq the weaker one...really minimum transformations   

Comment: @fabio_iaci, so you always make use of both channels? To be honest I have never even considered using the "weak" channel to beef up the main one because I find the off-axis coloration too pronounced, but like we say in France: who doesn't try doesn't get. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with my DR-100. I find it sounds better to point one capsule only at the source recording in stereo, not mixing both channels into mono.

PS: and drop the non-used side of your headphones, it makes things much easier by not distracting/polluting your monitoring judgement.